# All AngularJS Controllers Not Loading with LazyLoad

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, lazy-loading, angularjs-controller

I am trying to lazy load my controllers for my AngularJS app I built along side with requireJS.  I have created a custom "lazyLoad" library that creates a resolve object in app.config() routes (also I am using ui-router).  If I code the state (without my library) to look like so it works

```
define(['angular', 'lazyLoader', 'uiRouter'], function(angular, lazyLoader, uiRouter){

    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

    app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) {


        window.lazy = {
            controller: $controllerProvider.register,
            directive: $compileProvider.directive,
            filter: $filterProvider.register,
            factory: $provide.factory,
            service: $provide.service
        };

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
            .state('campaigns', {
                url:'/campaigns',
                views: {
                    "top-nav"  : {
                        templateUrl: 'views/home/top-nav.html',
                        resolve : {
                            load : ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope){
                                var d = $q.defer();
                                require(['../app/controllers/header-controller'], function() {
                                    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                                        d.resolve();
                                    });
                                });
                                return d.promise;
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    "fullpage": {
                        templateUrl: 'views/home/index.html',
                        resolve : {
                            load : ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope){
                                var d = $q.defer();
                                require(['../app/controllers/home-controller'], function() {
                                    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                                        d.resolve();
                                    });
                                });
                                return d.promise;
                            }]
                        }
                        //controller: 'home-controller'
                    }
                }
            });

    });

    return app;

});
```

If I attempt to replace the resolve object with my library function it looks would look like this:

```
define(['angular', 'lazyLoader', 'uiRouter'], function(angular, lazyLoader, uiRouter){
```

and

```
.state('home', lazyLoader.route({
    url:'/',
    views: {
        "top-nav"  : {
            templateUrl: 'views/home/top-nav.html',
            controllerUrl: '../app/controllers/header-controller'
        },
        "fullpage": {
            templateUrl: 'views/home/index.html',
            controllerUrl: '../app/controllers/home-controller'
        }
    }
}));
```

**lazyLoader.js**

```
define(function () {
    'use strict';
    function LazyLoader() {}
    LazyLoader.prototype.route = function(config){
        var controllerPath;
        if(config && config.views){
            var singleView = Object.keys(config.views);
            for(var i in singleView){
                var viewName = singleView[i];
                controllerPath = config.views[viewName].controllerUrl;
                delete config.views.controllerUrl;
                config.views[viewName].resolve = {
                    load : ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope){
                        var d = $q.defer();
                        require([controllerPath], function() {
                            $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                                d.resolve();
                            });
                        });
                        return d.promise;
                    }]
                };
            }
        }
        return config;
    }
    return new LazyLoader();
});
```

**Example Controller**

```
define(['app/module'], function (module) {
    lazy.controller('header-controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        // stuff here
    }]);
});
```

On a side note I plan on implementing something better than attaching lazy variable to window.

When I code the router like the first example it works.  When I use my lazyLoader the one of the two views loads it's controller, the second view's controller's file is started to load (console.logs at the beginning show this) but it cannot resolve "module" in the example above.

link to error: [AngularJS Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=lead-download-controller&p1=not%20aNaNunction,%20got%20undefined)

Again this issue only happens when using my lazyloader which is producing the same resolve object that I have hard coded in for the version that works.

I have searched high and low and there are a lot of resources out there but I could not find anything that addressed this issue.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You are taking too much pain to do lazy loading of controllers & services. There is simple approach to lazy load files with ocLazyLoad. This article might help you resolve the same issue. 
https://routerabbit.com/blog/convert-angularjs-yeoman-spa-lazyload/

What you should do is

Add a reference of ocLayzLoad & updated JS files’ reference to load on demand from app.js or .html file of their views.

```
`bower install oclazyload --save-dev`
```

Now load the module ‘oc.lazyLoad’ in application. Update app.js file

```
angular
      .module('helloWorldApp', [
        'ngCookies',
        'ngResource',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngSanitize',
        'oc.lazyLoad',
])
```

Load JS file by adding reference of JS in .html file

```
<div oc-lazy-load="['scripts/controllers/about.js', 'scripts/services/helloservice.js']">
     <div ng-controller="AboutCtrl as about">
            Your html goes here
     </div>
</div>
```

If you using Grunt, update Gruntfile to uglyfy, renamed file name & update references in the final .html or .js file.

Answer (score 0):

On the 'myApp' module definition, shouldn't you be returning `app` variable instead of `myApp`?

And to avoid exposing lazy to window, you could define it as a property of `app` variable, this way when  you define new functions, you require `app` first and you can use it:

**app.js**:

```
app.lazy = {
        controller: $controllerProvider.register,
        directive: $compileProvider.register,
        filter: $filterProvider.register,
        factory: $provide.factory,
        service: $provide.service
    };
...
return app;
```

**controller.js**:

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.lazy.controller('header-controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        // stuff here
    }]);
});
```

Comment: Sorry that's an error in my question code. I am returning app currently and still experiencing the error.

Comment: The rest looks fine to me, it's hard to say more without the rest of the code. But one thing I noticed, you're 'requiring' the controller file, but you're not assigning the controller's name to the states right?

Try setting it:

    "top-nav"  : {
        templateUrl: 'views/home/top-nav.html',
        controllerUrl: '../app/controllers/header-controller',
        controller: 'header-controller'
    },

Comment: I tried that too, sadly no results. Thanks for the input!